# Morris Js and Codeigniter pass data from a controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, morris.js

I have the following controller which picks data from my DBase :

function chart_js() {

```
    $rows = '';
    $query = "SELECT clnt_id,date_added FROM job_card ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0, 5";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $total_rows = $result->num_rows;
    if ($result) {
        $rows = $result->result_array();
    }
    print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

}
```

And passes it to json_encode in the following format :

```
[{"clnt_id": 10, "date_added": "2015-11-02 12:28:01"}, {"clnt_id": 11, "date_added": "2015-11-01 07:06:56"} , {"clnt_id": 9, "date_added": "2015-10-30 22:14:48"}, {"clnt_id": 7, "date_added": "2015-10-30 06:15:55"}, {"clnt_id": 10, "date_added": "2015-10-30 06:03:50"}]
```

The data above is the exact format of how the data is returned. 
I have used the above data to plot a static line graph and it worked very well. Below is my view :

```
<body class="nav-md">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Account Registrations Past 7 days
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="acctregs" style="height: 300px;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>



        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var acct_regs = [{"clnt_id": 10, "date_added": "2015-11-02 12:28:01"}, {"clnt_id": 11, "date_added": "2015-11-01 07:06:56"}
                    , {"clnt_id": 9, "date_added": "2015-10-30 22:14:48"}, {"clnt_id": 7, "date_added": "2015-10-30 06:15:55"}, {"clnt_id"
                                : 10, "date_added": "2015-10-30 06:03:50"}];
                var acctregs = new Morris.Line({
                    // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
                    element: 'acctregs',
                    // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
                    // the chart.
                    data: acct_regs,
                    // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
                    xkey: 'date_added',
                    // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
                    ykeys: ['clnt_id'],
                    // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
                    // chart.
                    labels: ['Value'],
                    dateFormat: function (x) {
                        return new Date(x).toString().split("00:00:00")[0];
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>

</body>
```

However when I try to retrieve this data from the controller which interacts with the Dbase by replacing the  var acct_regs to :

```
var acct_regs = "<?php echo site_url('operations/char_js'); ?>";
```

I get the  following error :

```
TypeError: a is undefined
    ...,h,i,j,k,l;return"number"==typeof a?a:(c=a.match(/^(\d+) Q(\d)$/),e=a.match(/^(\...
```

from morris.min.js. 
What is the  best way to pass this data from controller to view so that it can display dynamic graphs?

Comment: try adding `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in the `chart_js() `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ajax the data use `$.getJSON`

Try:

```
$.getJSON("<?php echo site_url('operations/char_js'); ?>", function (json) { 
            var acctregs = new Morris.Line({
                        // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
                        element: 'acctregs',
                        // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
                        // the chart.
                        data: json,
                        // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
                        xkey: 'date_added',
                        // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
                        ykeys: ['clnt_id'],
                        // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
                        // chart.
                        labels: ['Value'],
                        dateFormat: function (x) {
                            return new Date(x).toString().split("00:00:00")[0];
                        }
                    });
        });
```